# Login btn not clicking (Protractor TS)

Tags: typescript, protractor, pageobjects, cucumberjs

I created Page objects for home page and login page. Now I am trying to continue my test cases but I am having problem with login btn. Whem my test cases are running it's not clicking logIn btn. Is anyone had the same issue here?

```
let chai = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised"));
import { defineSupportCode } from 'cucumber';
import {browser, element, by, ElementFinder, $, $$ , until } from 'protractor' ;
const expect = chai.expect;
import { HomePage } from '../page-objects/pm360-home-page';
import { LoginPage } from '../page-objects/pm360-login-page';

   var pm360_homepage  = new HomePage();
   //var pm360_loginpage = new LoginPage();

  defineSupportCode(({Given,Then }) => {
  Given('I login into pm360 page with a valid authentication {string} and {string}',   
  async function givenauth(username: string, password: string): Promise<void>{
    pm360_homepage.OpenBrowser('https://pm360-qa.parkmobile.io/'); 
    await pm360_homepage.usernameField.sendKeys('.....');
    await pm360_homepage.passwordField.sendKeys('......');
    //browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Button.MIDDLE).click();
    pm360_homepage.ClickLogIn(); 
    //pm360_homepage.logInBtn.click().then(()=> {"looged In"});
    //browser.touchActions().tap(pm360_homepage.logInBtn).perform().then(()=> {"logged In"});
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});
   Given('I navigate through manage policies',
   async function givenmanaging():Promise<void>{
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //browser.wait(until.elementsLocated(pm360_homepage.managePoliciesBtn));
    await pm360_homepage.managePoliciesBtn.click();
    //browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your OpenBrowser() and ClickLogIn() functions returning promises? If they are you will have to add await for those promises too. The reason that button is not being clicked is because you have not used the await statements properly.

NOTE: You will have to await every promise you encounter, if any one of those promises escape the await, they will be executed synchronously thus giving your promise rejections. You will not understand it because your code will run and the test case will fail. Make sure you have set your `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your configuration file and make sure all your promises are handled properly.

Comment: I have that on my config but still have these issues

Comment: Yes because you are not handling all your promises properly. Look at your code and see if you are missing any awaits for any of your promises.